# Wann wird das stimmhafte "s" gesprochen?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

Da ich mit schwäbischem Dialekt aufgewachsen bin (in dem es das stimmhafte "s" [s̬] nicht gibt), bin ich immer unsicher, wann das "s" stimmhaft gesprochen wird, und wann nicht.

Beispiel:

> See [s̬eː] stimmhaft gesprochen im Hochdeutsch
>
> See [z̥eː] stimmlos in Süddeutschland

Gibt es eine Regel, nach der die Aussprache des "s" definiert ist?

Comment: Ich kann das stimmhafte S noch nichtmal aussprechen, deshalb ignoriere ich es geflissentlich. ^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wikipedia bietet eine [wunderbare Übersicht](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stimmhafter_alveolarer_Frikativ) darüber, wann das S stimmhaft gesprochen wird:

> im Anlaut vor Vokal, zwischen zwei Vokalen, zwischen [l], [m], [n], [ŋ], [r] und Vokal, sowie vor [l], [m], [n], [r], wenn es eine verwandte Wortform gibt, bei der vor diesen Konsonanten ein [Schwa](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa) gesprochen wird.
>
> - Beispiele: **S**age [ˈzaːgə] oder [ˈz̥aːg̥ə], Ha**s**e [ˈhaːzə] oder [ˈhaːz̥ə], un**s**er [ˈʊnzɐ], Mitbring**s**el [ˈmɪtbʁɪŋzl ̩], Pil**s**ner [ˈpʰɪlznɐ], un**s**re [ˈʊnzʁə]