# how to understand the difference between stimmloss and stimmhaft sound of 's'?

Tags: speaking, sound

I tried youtube, to understand the sound but am unable to distinguish among the two. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to post the links to the videos (links to the moment in question, please). The *s* varies a lot depending on dialect.

Comment: Please check this video, he explains it pretty well: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpfznEvimLc

Comment: Although the video might be confusing once he starts talking about dialects

Comment: Are you familiar with spoken English? The sound that “z” makes in English, e.g. in zoom, is a »stimmhaftes s«, because your vocal chords are actually involved in making that sounds (hence »stimmhaft«), whereas the sound that “s” makes, e.g. in some, is a »stimmloses s«, which is just the hissing sound without your vocal chords doing anything.

Comment: Can you hear the difference between voiced /v/ (as in English "very" or German "Weile") and voiceless /f/ (as in "ferry" or "Feile")? Can you pronounce both?

Comment: What is your first language? - Knowing this, we could tell you corresponding phones/phonems in your language, if they exist.

Comment: My first language is English. @Raketenolli, yeah now I am able to understand the sound of stimmthafte and stimmtlose characters.

Comment: @akshitbhatia   Okay, then Reketenolli's advice suits you. It is the difference of z in *zoom* vis à vis s in *sound*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you asked in English, I'll assume you are familiar with English pronunciation. The English words for *"stimmlos/stimmhaft"* are "unvoiced/voiced". The English voiced "s" is generally written as "z", if you pronounce it you should feel a vibration in your throat.
Pairs of English words with unvoiced/voiced "s" are:

- sue - zoo
- see - zee
- sink - zinc

German has the same unvoiced/voiced "s" ("s" can be either voiced or unvoiced, "ss" or "ß" is always unvoiced). The usage is different (and dialect dependent) , but that has been covered elsewhere on this site: [Wann wird das stimmhafte "s" gesprochen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/685/wann-wird-das-stimmhafte-s-gesprochen)

Comment: Might be worth adding that it's never voiced in the end of a word or before a voiceless consonant.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for relating this to english. Now I can better relate the stimmhafte alphabets in english and german. Great explaination.

Comment: Nice minimal pairs!